# Software to publish transcripts in multiple languages

Tags: gratis, web-apps, translation, multi-user

I would like to transcribe and publish a number of talks that will hopefully be translated to many different languages and so I am looking for something, some kind of wiki perhaps, that will help me do this.

My first thought was MediaWiki due to the well known Wikipedia site(s). Unfortunately it appears it is all a kludge and MediaWiki doesn't really have multilingual support from the ground up.

So my requirements are,

- User accounting
- Versioning
- Multimedia support **
- Multiple language support
- Search
- Free (this is **not** for commercial use so funds are limited), preferably open source

** I have been thinking about embedding an audio player, like [Sound Manager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) for example, though it is not critical.

What do you guys suggest?

Comment: Do you want to self-host it? (You used the [tag:open-source], but your question doesn’t mention it … is it required to be Open Source?)

Comment: @unor Self hosting is a possibility, I haven't decided. I used open-source since they they are usually free and easier to alter to fit specific needs. I happy to consider a free non-open source option.